# HTML value passed to WebService is showing NULL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a AJAX Web Serice that runs an SQL statment, which works.

I am trying to take an HTML value from my web page and use it as an additional variable in my query.

Here is how I am capturing that variable on my web page.

```
        <div style="margin-left:0px">
            <label>Enter Number here: </label><br>
            <input type= text id="demo">
        </div>
```

...and this is my Web Service call.

```
    //Generate code
    function Generate() {

        var myGrid = $('#jqquotes'),
            selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            docid = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'docid');


        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").value;

        alert(document.getElementById("demo").value);

        var quotenum = document.getElementById("demo".value);


        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to generate a quote?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/WebService1.asmx/Generate',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "GET",
                data: { docid: docid, quotenum: JSON.stringify(quotenum) }, 
                success: function () {

                    //Get selected
                    var grid = $("#jqquotes");
                    var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', "selrow");

                    //Refresh grid
                    $('#jqquotes').trigger('reloadGrid');

                    //Set Selected
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        jQuery('#jqquotes').jqGrid('setSelection', rowKey);
                    }, 200);


                }
            });

        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

The alert box correct displays the HTML value from the box id "Demo"

But the WebService fails, saying the value is NULL, JSON reponse is:
Message "The parameterized query '(@docid nvarchar(5),@quotenum nvarchar(4000))UPDATE [dbo].[quote' expects the parameter '@quotenum', which was not supplied."

...and the GET URL shows the value as NULL

https://localhost:44338/WebService1.asmx/Generate?docid=10146&quotenum=null

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
var quotenum = document.getElementById("demo".value);
```

This should be

```
var quotenum = document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

as in the line above it.